# deleting line without temporary file in C

Tags: c, file-handling

I'm trying to delete a given line by replacing that line by the next line but it doesn't change anything

```
int i=0,n,j,p;
char s[80];
FILE *fp;
scanf("%d",&n);
fp = fopen("test.txt","r+");
while(fgets(s,sizeof(s),fp)!=NULL){
    i++;
    if(i==n)
        break;
    j = ftell(fp);
}

while(fgets(s,60,fp)!=NULL){
    p = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp,0,j);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",s);
    j = p;
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_CUR);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: I don't think this will work for deleting the first line. You've already read past it when you set `j`.

Comment: I think your whole algorithm is messed up. If a line is shorter than the previous line, you'll overwrite only part of a line and then later read the rest of the replaced line. If the line is longer, you'll write too far. I haven't figured out precisely how to fix it, but it would be easier if you read fixed-size strings instead of reading by lines in the 2nd loop.

Comment: The fix to the problem @Barmar refers to is perhaps to move character-by-character rather than line-by-line.  It is very inefficient.  A simpler method may be to use a memory mapped file and simply `memmove()` the remainder of the file to the start of the line to be deleted.

Comment: @Clifford character-by-character is just a limiting case of fixed-size strings. Memory mapping is OS-specific. But you could also read the entire file into memory, seek to the line to be deleted, then write the part of the memory buffer after that line.

Comment: And in all these methods, you need to truncate the file after the final line, to remove the extra line at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong arguments in `fseek(fp, 0, j);`. The third argument needs to be one of the `SEEK_xxx` constants, so it should be `fseek(fp, j, SEEK_SET);`.